# Python: Most efficient way to count the parent folders in a path

Tags: python, path, pathlib

I am trying to find the most efficient way to count the amount of Parent folders in a path. For example this path: D:\Python\Projects\Old code\project_1, would have 3 parent folders, namely: \Python\Projects\Old code.

I have solved this by counting the amounts of \ (for windows), however, I was wondering if there is any build it in method to accomplish this, so I can achieve the same result across operating systems.

My current solution:

```py
def count_parents(path):
    return path.count("\\") - 1
```

(Windows) Example:
D:\Python\Projects\Old code\project_1
Should result in: 3

For Linux I expect of course the same result, but without having to check if the string has \ or / to count the amount of parents

I would be very grateful for whoever can solve this efficiently!
(I tried googling this question but couldn't find a solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a variant:

```
def count_parents(path):
    return len(path.parts) - 2
    # or:
    # return len(path.parents) - 1
```

see [`path.parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#pathlib.PurePath.parts) and [`Path.parents`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#pathlib.PurePath.parents).